# java.io.IOException: Destination ''\\192.168.1.40\Documents' directory cannot be created

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-commons, ioexception

I try to upload document and images to the network location. i have the code below

```
File temp = new File(url);
                     if (temp.isDirectory() && !temp.exists()) {
                     temp.mkdir();
                     }
                     String fileType="." +FilenameUtils.getExtension(bean.getUploadFileName().get(j));
                     Date date = new Date();
                     String fileName = String.valueOf(date.getTime()) /*+ i*/;
                     String documentPath = url +fileName+fileType;
                     FileUtils.copyFile(bean.getUpload().get(j), new File(documentPath));
```

it is working in the when i use Eclipse IDE to run the server. But when i Run Apache Tomcat Server with out IDE i face some Exception for Directory creation.

> java.io.IOException: Destination '\192.168.1.40\Documents' directory
>   cannot be created     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1082)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1040)

how to i upload the document in network location.

Comment: How did you specify the file name? Note there is only one backslash in the error message. Did you forget to double the backslash in a string constant (`"\\\\192.168 ..."`)?

Comment: i tried the path setting "//192.168.1.40/Documents/","////192.168.1.40//Documents//","\\192.168.1.40\\Documents\\",,"\\\\192.168.1.40\\\\Documents\\\\". but i got the same exception

Comment: try with `"\\\\192.‌​168.1.40\\Document‌​s\\"` ("\" need to be escaped in java string with another "\", so to get two you need 4